# Sequential display of a images list with jsf,richfaces

Tags: javascript, image, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, sequential

I have a big problem and i need your help.

My application is with JSF and rich faces. I have a list of Image in my model (imageModel):

```
import java.awt.Image;
List<Image> liste_images = new ArrayList<Image>()
```

and i have to play them one by one (every 3 seconds one of them is display ) in the same place.

Please some help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use Primefaces - dynamic image streaming
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf

inside the primefaces galleria component:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/galleria.jsf

Checkout the links to the showcase site for examples

Comment: Thank you for your response zargarf,
In this example they used a list of String (Url of picture)
But in my application i use a list of Image (ImageIO) 
that's the deference ..

thanks

Comment: No replay ?!!
please help me Zargarf !